# Pagination AJAX, need to include js all the time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have page.php with about 10 JS files:

PAGE.PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile3.js"></script>
...
<div id="pictures"></div>
...
```

in this page I have some pictures, that need all this js, and a AJAX function to do an pagination after each 10 pictures:

AJAX

```
next page ->

$.post('/LOADMORE.php',{
    'group_no': track_load,
    'idpag': idpag
},
```

Ok, when user click in next page the AJAX will call LOADMORE.PHP to load more pictures in **div id="pictures"**

this pictures need some Jquery (as the pictures above - this jquery functions is in PAGE.PHP already) functions to open pictures bigger in the screen and other things.

What happening is that the scripts in PAGE.PHP does not work with the pictures loaded using AJAX pagination. So I need to include all 10 js files in LOADMORE.PHP too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile3.js"></script>
<?php
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?");
    ...
    while($l = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo"<img src=$picture>";
    }
?>
```

- My question 1 is, is it right, do I need to include JS in loadmore.php for this to work?
- Question 2: if it is right, there is no problem that this `<script>` in loadmore.php is not on the `<head>` tag? because the loadmore.php is just a PHP function that select pictures in mysql and bring it to the user, there is no `<head><title><body>...` should I use this tags?

Comment: this sounds like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). i 'm nearly positive there is a simpler, cleaner way to accomplish your end result, but you haven't explained what that end result is!

Comment: Solution depends on what the code does. If it is all event handlers ...solution is simple. If there are plugins involved it will be different. Show samples of the script code

Comment: @charlietfl I edit it with some simple parts of my code, I think it sum up what it is about.

Comment: Do you mean that the javascript listener doesn't work on your ajax called page ?

Comment: yeah, I need to include the <script> tag for this to work @frz3993

Comment: I take it that you bind the event listener on document ready. The easier way is to use event attribute on the element (eg. onclick) that will call a javascript function. Or you can bind the event listener to an element that exist during document ready (eg the parent of the ajax div);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you should use switch-case for this to work properly. There is no need to include all files in all pages and u don't have to use all that tags in LOADMORE file.
Do 1 thing use switch case give page name as case and in that perticular page use all JS files you are desire to. As shown below by using this method you don't have to include unnecessary files in all pages and your code just work fine. For Ex:-

```
switch($page)
{
case "PAGE":
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile3.js"></script>
break;
case "LOADMORE":
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile6.js"></script>
break;
default:
<script type="text/javascript" src="commonjs1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="commonjs2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="commonjs3.js"></script>
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you giving an unique id to the containers or elements of the pictures you load in LOADMORE.PHP ?
If you do so and they make sense for your js in PAGE.PHP... should just work